# How can I forced Moin Moin to run FastCGI socket?

Tags: fastcgi, moinmoin

When using the moin.fcg (appropriately adjusted for the installation)
from version 1.9.6, the fastcgi process fails to start correctly.

The failing process logs the following on start:-

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help much with fastcgi stuff as I personally just use apache2/mod-wsgi (doing WSGI directly is much simpler), but the error you get is rather clear: wsgi needs that stuff noted in the log output. Maybe you need to configure your server to provide that.

BTW: this is in no way moin specific, so you maybe should rather ask how to make any WSGI application work with your server and fastcgi (moin uses flup as adapter).

If you find out that something provided in the moin download archive is wrong or could be improved, please contact us.